# Java NIO client causes file descriptor leakage only when remote TCP server is down

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp, nio

The below program acts as TCP client and uses NIO to open socket to a remote server, as below

```
private Selector itsSelector;
private SocketChannel itsChannel;

public boolean getConnection(Selector selector, String host, int port)
{
    try
    {
        itsSelector = selector;
        itsChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        itsChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        itsChannel.register(itsSelector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
        itsChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
        if (itsChannel.isConnectionPending())
        {
            while (!itsChannel.finishConnect())
            {
                // waiting until connection is finished
            }
        }
        itsChannel.register(itsSelector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        return (itsChannel != null);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        close();
        if(ex instanceof ConnectException)
        {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "The remoteserver cannot be reached");
        }
    }
}

public void close()
{
    try
    {
        if (itsChannel != null)
        {
            itsChannel.close();
            itsChannel.socket().close();
            itsSelector.selectNow();
        }
}   
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Connection cannot be closed");
    }
}
```

This program runs on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)
When number of concurrent sockets are in establishment phase, file descriptor limit reaches a max value and I see below exception while trying to establish more socket connections.

```
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
```

This happens only when the remote Node is down, and while it is up, all is fine.
When the remote TCP server is down, below exception is thrown as is handled as IOException in the above code

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any way to forcefully close the underlying file descriptor in this case.
Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Why would you configure blocking false and then block anyway?

Comment: According to the Javadoc, it should be closed automatically by the nio library: "If a connection attempt fails, that is, if an invocation of this method throws a checked exception, then the channel will be closed.".

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt To clarify, that text comes from the description of `finishConnect()`, which shouldn't even be being called here.

Comment: Even after explicitly closing the SocketChannel(itsChannel.close) and itsChannel.isOpen() returning false , the underlying file descriptor is not being closed

Comment: @SupriyaKulkarni You don't know that. It could be a descriptor for something else, for example a Selector.

Comment: How do we close the selector, when we intend to close the connection ? itsSelector.close(); ?

Comment: @SupriyaKulkarni Of course, but you don't have to close the selector at all. You can just keep using the same one. If you're creating mutiple Selectors, say one per connect, that's the problem. Don't.

Answer (score 4):

```
private Selector itsSelector;
```

I cannot see the point of this declaration. You can always get the selector the channel is registered with, if you need it, which you never do. Possibly you are leaking *Selectors?*

```
itsChannel.configureBlocking(false);
itsChannel.register(itsSelector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
```

Here you are registering for `OP_CONNECT` but never making the slightest use of the facility.

```
itsChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
```

Here you are starting a pending connection.

```
if (itsChannel.isConnectionPending())
```

It is. You just started it. The test is pointless.

```
{
    while (!itsChannel.finishConnect())
    {
        // waiting until connection is finished
    }
}
```

This is just a complete waste of time and space. If you don't want to use the selector to detect when `OP_CONNECT` fires, you should call `connect()` *before* setting the channel to non-blocking, and get rid of this pointless test and loop.

```
    itsChannel.register(itsSelector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
    return (itsChannel != null);
```

`itsChannel` cannot possibly be null at this point. The test is pointless. You would be better off allowing the `IOExceptions` that can arise to propagate out of this method, so that the caller can get some idea of the failure mode. That also places the onus on the caller to close on *any* exception, not just the ones you're catching here.

```
catch (IOException ex)
{
    close();
    if(ex instanceof ConnectException)
    {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "The remoteserver cannot be reached");
    }
}
```

See above. Remove all this. If you want to distinguish `ConnectException` from the other `IOExceptions`, *catch* it, separately. And you are forgetting to log anything that *isn't* a `ConnectException`.

```
public void close()
{
    try
    {
        if (itsChannel != null)
        {
            itsChannel.close();
            itsChannel.socket().close();
            itsSelector.selectNow();
```

The second `close()` call is pointless, as the channel is already closed.

```
catch (IOException e)
{
    LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Connection cannot be closed");
}
```

I'm glad to see you finally logged an `IOException`, but you're not likely to get any here.

Don't write code like this.

Comment: "I'm glad to see you finally logged an IOException, but you're not likely to get any here." Not likely, but still posible, however if that fails your program should abort :). Good answer.

Comment: The root cause of file descriptor leakage in my case was the Selector not being closed, when connection fails to establish or the remote server is down. When the closed the selector in catch block of getConnection method, the issue is solved

Comment: @SupriyaKulkarni That's a poor solution. You're closing a Selector that was provided by somebody else. The actual problem is the somebody else creating endless Selectors. You only need one for the life of the program.

Comment: Indeed we use  a single selector to initiate a TCP client connection towards Server. And once successful, we keep on using the same. Only when the previous request to Server fails (indicating server is down), as part of failover logic we open new connection towards one of the two servers(by using a new Selector) , and this happens whenever we get  a new call . That's the reason of Selector leakage only when TCP Server is down.

Comment: Opening a new connection does not require creating a new Selector. Nothing does. Don't.